# How to make a folder which contains many files in Java?

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I want to make a folder which contains files that my program made. For example (this example doesn't represent the things that my program actually does):

```
private static HashMap<LocalDate,Number> numbers = new HashMap<>();
private static ListIterator li;
public static void saveIndividually(){
    try{
    if(!numbers.isEmpty()){
        ArrayList<LocalDate> lista= new ArrayList<LocalDate>(numbers.keySet());
        li=lista.listIterator(); 
        while (li.hasNext()){
            Number number=numbers.get(li.next());
            FileOutputStream ostreamPassword = new FileOutputStream(number.getDate()+".dat");
            ObjectOutputStream oosPass = new ObjectOutputStream(ostreamPassword);
            oosPass.writeObject(number);
            ostreamPassword.close();     
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Error de IO: " + ioe.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

- My program makes random numbers combination.
- Every combination is stored in a `HashMap` like so( I've added new code):
And now I want to make a .txt document individually for every number in the `HashMap`, with the name `datetime(when the number was created).txt`, and introduce  all of them in a folder to make it easy for the user to read the combination without starting my program. Is it possible to do that in Java?

Comment: Yes, this is possible in Java. Have you tried to do this at all?

Comment: Break the problem into smaller pieces and have a go.

Comment: The only thing that I don´t have is the part to introduce all them in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's answer "*How to make a folder - in java*". There are several ways to do this. Let's create an output folder on the Desktop for demonstration.

```
public static File createOutputFolder() {
   final File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop")
   final File output = new File(desktop, "output");

   if (!output.exists()) {
          // The directory does not exist already, we create it
          output.mkdirs();
    } else if (!output.isDirectory()) {
          throw new IllegalStatexception("The output path already exists but is no directory: " + output);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Our method also returns the output directory. You may now pass this `File` object to your `FileOutputStream` and create new files like that:

```
File output = createOutputFolder();
FileOutputStream ostreamPassword = new FileOutputStream(new File(output, number.getKey()+".dat"));
```

Hopefully this answered your question. If not, please be more specific about the problem.